# I need help in editing colour of a a mobile navigation bar via Additional CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using the NewsCard theme and since I got the free version, I used the additional CSS field to customize the colours of the website. (usually, this can be done in the pro version of the theme only) Since I am not a developer, I picked up a code from a tutorial, chose my colours, edited them, and everything went great except for one thing. For mobile and tablet versions the navigation bar still has the default theme colour. All other colour changes are ok on those displays except this one.

Could someone help me out? I will paste my code from the Additional CSS field below.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Piazzolla:wght@500&display=swap');

* {font-family: 'Piazzolla', serif;}

/*** Top Bar ***/
.info-bar {
    background-color: ;
}

.info-bar ul li, .info-bar .social-profiles ul li a, .info-bar .infobar-links ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}


/*** Nav Bar BG Color ***/
.navigation-bar {
    background-color: #FF5533 !important;
}

/*** Home - Titles ***/
h3.stories-title, .stories-title {
    border-left: 4px solid #FF5533;
}

/*** Home - Post Titles ***/
.post-boxed .entry-title, .post-block .entry-title, .post-boxed.main-post.inlined .entry-title {
    font-weight: 500;
}

/*** Home - Widget Titles ***/
.widget-title {
    border-left: 4px solid #FF5533;
}


/*** Home - Just Img ***/
.post-img-wrap .entry-meta .cat-links a {
    background-color: #1e1f1e;
}

/*** Home - Img + Title ***/
.post-img-wrap + .entry-header .entry-meta .cat-links a {
    background-color: #1e1f1e;
}

/*** Home - Cat Text ***/
.entry-meta .cat-links a {
    color: #ef3f49;
}

/*** Home - Search Button ***/
.btn-theme {
    background-color: #1e1f1e;
}

/*** Single Posts - Body & Title ***/
.entry-content p {
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: ;
      font-weight:300;
        color: #000;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.entry-header h1.entry-title {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-family: 'Piazzolla', serif;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: lato;
}

/*** Category Page Post Title***/

.entry-header h2.entry-title {
    font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.3em;
        font-weight: 500;
    color: #333333; }

/*** Sidebar ***/
.post-boxed.inlined .entry-title, .post-block .entry-title {
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.post-col .entry-meta .cat-links a {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
}
/*** Mobile Nav Bar ***/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navigation-bar {
    background-color: #FF5533 ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the !important flag from the rule:

```
/*** Nav Bar BG Color ***/
.navigation-bar {
    background-color: #FF5533;
}
```

otherwise add the flag also to the rule inside the media query

```
/*** Mobile Nav Bar ***/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navigation-bar {
        background-color: #7799BB !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I’ve just noticed you specify the same colour on both rules.

Comment: Update the background-color in the mobile nav bar to whatever you want

Comment: Whatever colour I put in it always stays the default for mobile and tablet. Even when I have the !important command on both places, on neither or on one of those it's the same all the time. Every other colour can be changed with no issues.